# I am implementing Oracle UCM in iPad application is there any web services for login authentication?

Tags: ios, web-services, ipad, oracle-ucm

I am implementing Oracle UCM in iPad application is there any web services for login authentication. now i am using the j_security_check?.. i am unable to handle j_security_check response.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://serveripaddress/cs/idcplg/j_security_check?"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//initialize a post data
NSString *postData =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"j_username=%@&j_password=%@",usernameTF.text,passwordTF.text];

NSLog(@"userDetails : %@" ,postData);

//set request content type we MUST set this value.
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *urlconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

self.connection = urlconnection;
```

Comment: Which `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods did you implement, can you add the code?

Comment: -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data; -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
- ( void )connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *)response; ...i am getting the html string as response..but is there any web-services to get response like status message

Comment: What do you mean by 'status message'? You mean http status code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iPad app for Webcenter Content rather than building your own app for the same . Please check the following links for app specific details :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e26695/mobile_integration.htm

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oracle-webcenter-content/id701199944?mt=8

Hope this helps .

Thanks,
Srinath

Comment: Links can break. Please add the required info here that address the problem.